# How do I create an iterator that invalidates the previous result each time `next` is called?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm using FFI to access data from elsewhere. My FFI API returns pointers to data allocated and owned by the C API. I don't have the option to have the C implementation use memory allocated by Rust.

When implementing my API, I want to create an `Iterator` that produces a `&[u8]` per `next()`, but the catch is that every time I call `next()`, the `&[u8]` generated by the previous call to `next()` becomes invalidated.

Here's my C API:

```
extern {
  // open an iterator, return a "ctx" void*
  fn read_open() -> *mut libc::c_void;
  // read the next value of the iterator. The return value is
  // invalidated when read_next or read_free is called
  fn read_next(ctx : *mut libc::c_void, data_len : *mut libc::size_t) -> *const libc::void_t;
  fn read_free(ctx : *mut libc::c_void);
}
```

How would you create a safe Rusty wrapper around this API such that the data returned by `read_next` doesn't need to be copied? I would like the object to be `Iterator`-able.